# Can I add/change additional parameters for the Authorization request with the default oauth2 client

Tags: java, spring-security-oauth2

I need to integrate Java Spring Security OAuth2 client to a particular IDP. I need to keep the /login url, so I cannot use custom ClientRegistrations, though I do need to add one additional parameter - nonce and to change the value of the return_type.

I have implemented a CustomAuthorizationRequestResolver OAuth2AuthorizationRequestResolver so that I change the additionalParameters but it requires oauth2Login() in the WebSecurity which on it's turn requires clientRegistrationRepository ant there is the problem. Using this clientRegistrationRepository makes the oauth use the /login/oauth2/authorization/{registrateionId} redirect uri pattern and if I do not adhere to it it does not recognize my oauth client.